# AXLSX: Conditional formatting for percent, changes the cell value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, axlsx

I'm following this example [LINK](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/conditional_formatting/example_conditional_formatting.rb). But, I have floating value for the cell, so when I run this example with every cell value as `4.5` (hardcoded), the excel generates cells with value `450.00 %`, while expected value was `4.500 %`.

**NOTE:** I have just changed line 26 of above example from:

```
ws.add_row ["Q#{i}", 10000*((rows/2-i) * (rows/2-i)), "=100*B#{i}/SUM(B3:B#{rows+offset})"], :style=>[nil, money, percent]
```

to:

```
ws.add_row ["Q#{i}", 10000*((rows/2-i) * (rows/2-i)), "4.5"], :style=>[nil, money, percent]
```

Just hard-coded `4.5`

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

How to add just a `%` sign to cell value without changing cell value?

Also, I don't wanr cell to be `:string` formatted, it has to be `:float`

Comment: `4.5 == 450%`, not `4,500%`. So I don't understand why you're expecting that to be the result. If you hardcode `450%`, then it's going to display `450%`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to display a number as a percentage without having it multiplied by 100 (*per-cent*!), but I'm also not sure why that's a problem in the first place.

Comment: @TomLord The values come dynamically. If I do like `cell.value = "#{value} %"`, then I get `4.5 %`, but that becomes string column. So, I wanted the value to be untouched (numeric) and just add an `%`.

Comment: @TomLord Now, as per your suggestion `4.5 = 450%`, I'm trying to divide every cell value with 100, so outcome is `0.045 = 4.5%`. Thanks. But, I was always expecting that when we give `:format_code => "0.00%"`, then output should be with 2 place decimal and `%` symbol.

Comment: Your screenshot above shows two trailing zeros. Now you're saying that the trailing zeros have vanished?

Comment: @Tom I don't understand what you are talking about. My simple requirement was, if the value is `4.5` then just append `%` and say `4.5 %`. Now, I gave format code 0.00 % because I wanted to retain 2 places decimal. So, even if the value is 1, it should put 1.00 %

Comment: We've already established a solution to the `4.5` vs `450` problem, which is that you must divide by 100. You're now presenting a second problem, which is that - you claim - the trailing zero is missing (`4.5%` instead of `4.50%`). I don't understand why that would happen, because providing a format value of `0.00%` seems correct to me. Additionally, **the screenshot you showed above** already appears to correctly include the two decimal places. So why has the second decimal place now vanished? Did you change anything else?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, if something confuses you, but I have already fixed my issue by dividing with 100. So, the problem is solved. BTW, I was just conveying what I misunderstood the use of format_code: 0.00 %.